# Using a link in the first jQuery-CSS tab to get to the third tab and preventing tab switchback on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm using jQuery to create a tab list; and when one of the 4 tabs are clicked, it'll take you to the content inside the hidden div. And of course, there are 4 hidden divs, one per tab.

Unfortunately, I'm  a jQuery Noob, and although there are a couple of things that I'd like to get done, I don't yet possess the skills to do that. And hence, you folks visiting stackoverflow are my only hope. Could either of these be accomplished? If yes, kindly do let me know.

1. Using a link in the first tab to get to the third tab. Like so: Go to tab 3. But this doesn't work. I'm guessing
   there should be some kind of a function which goes like:
   onClick="goToThatDiv()".
2. While on tab-2, if refreshed, the page will reload with tab-1, as
       the first tab has the class: current. Is there anyway that one could
       stay on the second tab even after refreshing the page?

Here are the highlights of the code:

## HTML

```
<!-- BEGINNING OF TABS DIV-->
<div id="tab_container">

        <!-- BEGINNING OF Tab list-->
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab 1</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab 2</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab 3</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab 4</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END OF Tab list-->



   <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"><!-- BEGINNING OF CURRENT DIV-->
      // Tab 1 Content goes here.
        <a href=" // link to the 3rd tab "> To the 3rd Tab </a>
        <a href=" // link to the 4th tab "> To the 4th Tab </a>
   </div> <!-- END OF CURRENT DIV-->


   <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"><!-- BEGINNING OF 2nd DIV-->
      // Tab 2 Content goes here.
   </div> <!-- END OF 2nd DIV-->


   <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"><!-- BEGINNING OF 3rd DIV-->
      // Tab 3 Content here.
   </div> <!-- END OF 3rd DIV-->


   <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"><!-- BEGINNING OF 4th DIV-->
      // Tab 4 Content here.
   </div> <!-- END OF 4th DIV-->


</div><!-- END OF TABS DIV-->
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})
</script>
```

CSS

```
/*****************Tabs CSS**********************/


        ul.tabs{

            list-style: none;
        }
        ul.tabs li{
            background:black;
            display: inline-block;

        }

        ul.tabs li:hover {
            background: blue;

        }

        ul.tabs li.current{
            background: green;

        }

        .tab-content{
            display: none;

        }

        .tab-content.current{
            display: inherit;
        }

/*****************End of Tabs CSS**********************/
```

Comment: JSfiddle please. I'm not sure why this functionality would be required. You'd have to use a cookie or local storage I think otherwise a different user wouldn't get the right experience.

Comment: Right, sorry about that.   [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uCLDK)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of them are possible.

**Solution to point 1**

- You can hide all the tab contents initially, except of course the first tab.
- Then when you click on any one of the tabs, check if its `data-tab` matches the respective tab `id`. Use `if else` for this.
- If you want a link to do this, give it the same `data-tab` and the same `onClick` Listener.
- Now, if they match, remove the `current` class from the tab which has this class and add it to the new tab whose `data-tab` matches the tab `id` of the tab content sought.
- Hide all the tab contents and show only the tab content which has the class `current`

**Solution to point 2**

- When a tab is clicked, change the window's location as follows

  `var href = $(this).data('tab');
  window.location.hash = href`

  this will behave as the url to the tab content
- Then when you reload the page, notice everything on the page resets to initial state, but the hash remains consistent.
- Now check for the tab content which matches the hash stored in the url as follows

  `$('.tab-link').each(function(){
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      var href = $(this).data('tab');
      if(hash==href)
      {
          // set the current tab's class as current
          // hide all the tab contents and show only current tab's content
      }
  });`

This can be daunting at first but once you understand it, it's pretty straightforward

**Reference**

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply man. Regarding the 1st solution, could you dumb it down a bit more, if that's even possible. D'oh! :\

Comment: If you want to display a link which shows contents of the 3rd tab (say) you could just copy the `li` tab which does this and paste it in the content where you want it.

this would work if you've got the tabs working alright

Comment: Ah-hah! yep, that does work; sort of. But according to your first solution, would you care to fill in the question marks for this newbie please? <a href="?"  data-tab="tab-3" onClick="?">Link to tab 3</a>

Comment: <a href="#" class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3" onClick="**a function which hides all the content areas and display only the content area which a class corresponding to tab 3**">Link to tab 3</a>

If you want to see how I did it, have a look at my website http://www.pixelvalet.com.

There all the three sections on the bottom left would behave as your **tabs** and the content on the right the **tab content**. So when you click any of the links on the bottom left, everything vanishes and only the relevant content is shown. Study the myScript.js file and do mark this answer if it was of any help :)

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. Checked codepen, and it does work. One last question though. When the link to the 3rd tab is clicked, after reaching the 3rd tab, is there anyway to highlight the 3rd tab as it would've looked had it been directly clicked?